# Runtime Error while Scanning a multidimensional array in C

Tags: c, file, scanf

I have a program that allows me to calculate the spread of viruses that occur within N seconds. My program takes input from the data.in file which contains something like this:

```
3 // How many testcases
3 1 // 3 is size of maps of the body that will be infected by the virus, and 1 is how many seconds it will spread.
###
###
V##

3 2
###
###
V##

3 3
###
###
V##
```

For every second virus spread around the body `#` maps. But my problem is, every 1 testcase, there must be a separator between the first testcase and the second testcase, where the separator is enter (\ n). I separate each testcase with fget (); however, the online judge gave me a run-error (10) which means that only 1 testcase out of 10 test cases was successful, and the rest gave run-errors.

Here is my code I tried to make :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int cases,size,time;
    char body[500][500];
    FILE *fptr = fopen("data.in","r");
    fscanf(fptr,"%d\n",&cases);

    for(int i = 0; i < cases; i++){
        fscanf(fptr,"%d %d\n",&size, &time); 

        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            fscanf(fptr,"%[^\n]\n", body[j]); 
        }
        fscanf(fptr,"\n");
        int newTime = time - 1; 

        for(int k = 0; k < size; k++){
            for(int l = 0; l < size; l++){
                if(body[k][l] == 'V'){
                    for(int m = k - newTime; m <= k + newTime; m++){
                        for(int n = l - newTime; n <= l + newTime; n++){
                            body[m][n] = '1'; // Flagging
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        printf("#%d:\n",i + 1);
        for(int o = 0; o < size; o++){
            for(int p = 0; p < size; p++){
                if(body[o][p] == '1') printf("V");
                else printf("#");
            } 
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

My output :

```
#1:
###
###
V##

#2:
###
VV#
VV#

#3:
VVV
VVV
VVV
```

However, my program already gives the right output, but when I submit into the online judge, it give me runtime error. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: what's an online judge?

Comment: You must not read nor write outside allocated arrays. Out-of-bound write will happen at `body[m][n] = '1';`.

Comment: @machine_1 it's similar to vjudge.net, he checks our coding using a system that checks every case

Comment: Fyi, `%d` ignores leading white-space, including newlines. `fscanf(fptr,"\n");` is completely pointless.You're going to hit `%d` anyway when scanning the upcoming dimensions of the next test.

Comment: @MikeCAT so, should I set the array into zero in every testcase? anyway, the constraints is only until body[100][100], but i give many extra spaces so it can works, but it doesnt:/ (anyway, I already did it by move the char body[100][100] = {{}}; into the loop for testcase, but it still gives runtime error :\

Comment: @iMax No, you don't need to set `body` into zero because the area to be read in that will be overwritten by the input. The extra space will save you from using too big index, but it won't save you from using too small (negative) index.

Comment: It's not wise to allocate 250kb on the stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m` and `n` may be negative value at the line `body[m][n] = '1'; // Flagging`.

It means out-of-bounds write may happen at the line and it may lead to Runtime Error.

To fix this, you should check if the values are in desired range before accessing like this:

```
if (0 <= m && m < size && 0 <= n && n < size) {
    body[m][n] = '1'; // Flagging
}
```

Now you will get Wrong Answer (for destroying `V` before dealing with that) or Time Limit Exceeded (for ineffiicient `O(size^2 * time^2)` solution), but Runtime Error will be eliminated.

Comment: Ok, I see what is my mistake. Thanks!